# How to write a Linq that can retrieve all parent table records and total of sub-table record, I mean 'separate' into two parts

Tags: linq, join

Let's say I have two tables, parent table 'P' and sub-table 'S', I usually wrote the Linq like this to get what I want:

```
var rows = from p in db.P
           join s in db.S on p.Id equals s.ParentId into subContent
           where (some condition here)
           select new{
                Id = p.Id,
                Title = p.Title
                SubContentCount = subContent.Count()
           }
```

It's very simple, but if for some reason I have to pass a parameter into this query when there has one (let's say 'key'), I have to do this (I guess :-):

```
var rows = from p in db.P
           join s in db.S on p.Id equals s.ParentId into subContent
           where (some condition here)
           select p;

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(key)){ // I'm using C#
   rows = rows.Where(q => q.Title.Contains(key))
}
```

And then:

```
var list = rows.Select(q => new ()
           {
                Id = q.Id,
                Title = q.Title,
                subCount = ???.Count()
            });
```

Is that passable to do Linq like this? if so, how?
Thanks for any kind help!

Comment: it seems like you wanna to filter the `parent` entity and get the count of the `sub-table` relationship, right?

Comment: @RubensFarias that's correct!

Comment: @RubensFarias Thanks for the real quick reply :-) I think your Lambda query will be work, but like I said before, the parameter 'key' passed into the query only if it exists, that's why I've mentioned on the title 'separate' the Linq into two parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a method that receives a `Func<Table, bool>`as parameter and use it to filter your dataset:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var rows = new List<Table>
    {
        new Table { Id = 1, Title = "A", SubContent = new [] { "A1" } },
        new Table { Id = 2, Title = "B", SubContent = new [] { "B1", "B2" } },
        new Table { Id = 3, Title = "C", SubContent = new [] { "C1", "C2", "C3" } },
    };

    var title = "C";
    foreach (var item in Filter(rows, table => 
        String.IsNullOrEmpty(title) || table.Title == title))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
            "Title={0}, SubContent.Length={1}",
            item.Title, item.SubContent.Length);
    }
}

public static List<Table> Filter(List<Table> original, Func<Table, bool> filter)
{
    return original.Where(filter).ToList();
}

public class Table
{
    public int      Id         { get; set; }
    public string   Title      { get; set; }
    public string[] SubContent { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help again :-) and your way works too!

Comment: TBH, I don't know if I understood your problem correctly =/

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I actually want to know if I have two or more where clauses, how to apply them on the query one by one and Select the result into a new object at the end.

Comment: You and @BurnsBA both put all the where clauses together and make a 'Select' once, I selected twice.

I'm not saying that I'm right, actually I should do your way if I have chances, just want to know more choices if there has one.

Comment: Well, you can also build the expressions: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/meek/2008/05/02/linq-to-entities-combining-predicates/

Comment: Yes, build all the where clauses into one Expression and pass it into Lambda, like this way more :-) just a little bit complicated for newer like me.

Comment: Since I'm going to use Expression, will give the credit to you and close this topic, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Why not include the filter in the where clause?

```cs
where string.IsNullOrEmpty(key) || p.Title.Contains(key)
```

Quick example in the interactive console:

```
public class Parent { public int Id {get; set;} public string Title {get; set;} }
public class SubTable { public int Id {get; set;} public int ParentId {get; set;} }
public class Result { public int Id {get; set;} public string Title {get; set;} public int SubContentCount {get; set;} }

var p1 = new Parent() { Id = 1, Title = "Parent_1" };
var p2 = new Parent() { Id = 2, Title = "Parent_2" };
var p3 = new Parent() { Id = 3, Title = "Parent_3" };
var s1_1 = new SubTable() { Id = 11, ParentId = 1 };
var s1_2 = new SubTable() { Id = 12, ParentId = 1 };
var s1_3 = new SubTable() { Id = 13, ParentId = 1 };
var s2_1 = new SubTable() { Id = 21, ParentId = 2 };
var s2_2 = new SubTable() { Id = 22, ParentId = 2 };
var s3_1 = new SubTable() { Id = 31, ParentId = 3 };

var db_P = new List<Parent>() { p1, p2, p3 };
var db_S = new List<SubTable>() { s1_1, s1_2, s1_3, s2_1, s2_2, s3_1 };

public IEnumerable<Result> GetResults(string key = null)
{
    var rows = from p in db_P
               join s in db_S on p.Id equals s.ParentId into subContent
               where string.IsNullOrEmpty(key) || p.Title.Contains(key)
               select new Result() {
                   Id = p.Id,
                   Title = p.Title,
                   SubContentCount = subContent.Count()
               };

    return rows;
}
```

And example output (formatted onto multiple lines for readability)

```
> GetResults().ToList()
    List<Submission#0.Result>(3) { 
        Submission#0.Result { Id=1, SubContentCount=3, Title="Parent_1" }, 
        Submission#0.Result { Id=2, SubContentCount=2, Title="Parent_2" }, 
        Submission#0.Result { Id=3, SubContentCount=1, Title="Parent_3" } 
    }
> GetResults("1").ToList()
    List<Submission#0.Result>(1) { 
        Submission#0.Result { Id=1, SubContentCount=3, Title="Parent_1" } 
    }
>
```

Comment: Yes, it does works! Thanks! but what if I really want to separate the Linq from one into two parts, is that passable?